# Haskell adding a polymorphic type

Tags: haskell

I am trying to add a polymorphic == to a data type. I have added the POLYEQ Var Var to data Exp and added Eval1 and Eval2:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances, FlexibleInstances #-}

data Exp = V Var
    | B Bool
    | L Exp
    | A Exp Exp
    | MyInt Int
    | And Exp Exp
    | Or Exp Exp
    | Not Exp
    | Mult Exp Exp
    | UnaryNeg Exp
    | LEQ Exp Exp
    | LESST Exp Exp
    | Add Exp Exp 
    | POLYEQ Var Var
data Var = VZ |VS Var

eval:: Exp -> Int
eval (MyInt e4)     = e4
eval (UnaryNeg e10)     = - (eval e10)
eval (Mult e11 e12) = eval e11 * eval e12
eval (Add e1 e2) = eval e1 + eval e2

eval0:: Exp -> Bool
eval0 (B e5) = e5
eval0 (Not e3) = not (eval0 e3)
eval0 (And e6 e7) = (eval0 e6) && (eval0 e7)
eval0 (Or e8 e9) = (eval0 e8) || (eval0 e9)
eval0 (LEQ e13 e14) = eval e13 <= eval e14
eval0 (LESST e15 e16) = eval e15 < eval e16

eval2:: Exp -> Var
eval2 (V e22) = e22

eval1:: a -> Bool
eval1 (POLYEQ e19 e20) = eval2 e19 == eval2 e20
```

But I get the followng error;

Exp.hs:37:32: error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Exp’ with actual type ‘Var’

• In the first argument of ‘eval2’, namely ‘e19’

  In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘eval2 e19’

  In the expression: eval2 e19 == eval2 e20
```

Exp.hs:37:45: error:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Exp’ with actual type ‘Var’

• In the first argument of ‘eval2’, namely ‘e20’

  In the second argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘eval2 e20’

  In the expression: eval2 e19 == eval2 e20
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

How can I make the == polymorphic?

---

edit:

```
eval1:: Exp -> Bool
eval1 (POLYEQ e19 e20) = eval e19 == eval e20
```

The file loads now, but when I run ti1 = POLYEQ (MyInt 4) (MyInt 7)
followed by eval1 ti1 I get the following error:

:100:7: error:
• Couldn't match expected type ‘Exp’

```
              with actual type ‘Exp -> Exp -> Exp’

• Probable cause: ‘POLYEQ’ is applied to too few arguments

  In the first argument of ‘eval1’, namely ‘POLYEQ’

  In the expression: eval1 POLYEQ

  In an equation for ‘it’: it = eval1 POLYEQ
```

Comment: Many things look suspicious. Why does the equality take two variables instead of two expressions? You also have defined a bunch of partial functions. You might be needing a type for values like `data Value = VI Int | VB Bool` to represent the value of an expression of unknown type.

Comment: Okay, how do I change the eval1 and eval2 to be polymorphic?

Comment: I just realized about the var to exp, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. First, to solve your actual problem, you should make the fields of the `POLYEQ` constructor of type `Exp`, not `Var`, otherwise you will only be able to compare variables.

Second, you should not split the `eval` function into multiple definitions like this. It looks like you’ve done so in order to return different types of results from each one: `Int` or `Bool`. But the effect of writing your code this way is that all of these functions are *partial*: `eval0` will *only* work on a subset of expressions, and will crash on others, and you can’t know ahead of time which function to call on an arbitrary `Exp` without examining it first.

A simple conventional approach is to add a type of *values* resulting from evaluation, for example:

```
data Val
  = IntVal Int
  | BoolVal Bool
```

With this, you can consolidate your functions into one, and tag the result of each case with the appropriate `Val` constructor. In addition, you don’t need to name all of your variables with distinct names, since they’re local to each case.

```
eval :: Exp -> Val

-- Evaluation of literals: tag the value with its type.
eval (MyInt i) = IntVal i
eval (B b) = BoolVal b

-- Evaluation of integer operations: match on ‘IntVal’.
-- This will raise an error if the expression did not return an integer.
eval (UnaryNeg e) = let
  IntVal i = eval e  -- Unwrap result, asserting that it’s an integer.
  in IntVal (- i)    -- Rewrap in ‘IntVal’ after applying negation.

eval (Mult e1 e2) = let
  IntVal i1 = eval e1
  IntVal i2 = eval e2
  in IntVal (i1 * i2)

-- Instead of just crashing, you may use explicit
-- pattern matching and handle the type error:
eval (Add e1 e2) = case (eval e1, eval e2) of
  (IntVal i1, IntVal i2) -> IntVal (i1 + i2)
  _ -> ... -- Decide what to do in the error case.

-- Fill in the remaining cases for each ‘Exp’ constructor.
```

For the `POLYEQ` case, you need to match on the results of evaluation to assert that they’re the same type, and compare accordingly:

```
eval (POLYEQ e1 e2) = case (eval e1, eval e2) of
  (IntVal i1, IntVal i2) -> BoolVal (i1 == i2)
  (BoolVal b1, BoolVal b2) -> BoolVal (b1 == b2)
  _ -> ... -- What do you want to do in this case?
           -- Return ‘BoolVal False’, raise an error, or something else?
```

However, this doesn’t describe how to evaluate lambda expressions (`L`) and variables. For that, you’ll need to add an additional argument to `eval` containing the variable environment (for example, a `[Val]`, where `VZ` looks up from the head, and `VS` looks up within the tail), and another constructor for `Val` to store a function value with its environment. However, this is beyond the scope of your current question.

Comment: -- What do you want to do in this case? I want to return true or false if the values or strings match

Comment: @pmichaels: The previous two branches of the `case` handle that. They return the result of comparing the values if they’re of the same type. But what if the input is `POLYEQ (MyInt 1) (B True)`? Do you consider that false, because they cannot be equal, being of different types; or do you consider it an error because they must be the same type in order to be compared? Basically, you need to decide what semantics you want here.